# laravel 5.4 eloquent create

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having a problem inserting a record into database table with `create`.

```
            // insert as chunks
            foreach (array_chunk($mainArr, 1000) as $chunk) {
                UnassignedTask::insert($chunk);
            }
            // insert as chunks
            foreach (array_chunk($matchUnmatchArr, 1000) as $chunk) {
                ProductMatchUnmatch::insert($chunk);
            }

            // for now ... remove this later.. in development
            $apiBody['status'] = "Completed";
            $projectsResponse = $this->postRemoteData($this->apiBaseUrl, 'search/searchprojectsbyclientdatestatus/?limit=500&offset=0', $apiBody, 'POST');            
            $prjResArr = json_decode($projectsResponse, true);
            $projects = $prjResArr['results'];
            foreach($projects as $pjt) {
                if($pjt['id'] != $reqId) {
                    continue;
                }
                $project = Project::where('project_id', intval($reqId))->first();
                if (!$project) {
                    //dd($pjt);
                    Project::create([
                        'client_code' => $pjt['client_name'],
                        'project_id' => $pjt['id'],
                        'file_name' => $pjt['file_name'],
                        'total_records' => $pjt['total_records'],
                        'total_unique_products' => $pjt['total_unique_products'],
                        'uploaded_datetime' => $pjt['start_date'],
                        'created_at' => $created_at,
                        'updated_at' => $updated_at
                        ]);

                }
            }
```

The issue is with `Project::create` that the record is not being inserted.

Notice that before inserting into `projects`, two other bulk `insert` transactions are performed in different tables : `UnassignedTask::insert()` and `ProductMatchUnmatch:insert()`.

If I comment these, then `Project::create` works.

But with these uncommented `Project::create` is not working.

EDIT:

Project.php

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';
    protected $fillable = ['client_code', 'project_id', 'file_name', 'total_records', 'total_unique_products', 'uploaded_datetime', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Show me your `Project` code

Comment: Can it be that you're inserting 2000 rows before it, that the script times out? You need to be more specific with "not working" - not working *how*? What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Developer I have updated the post. please do check.

Comment: @Qirel I get no errors. The transactions seem successful but then only former two tables get inserted and `projects` table don't.

Comment: Does it reach that part of the code? Add a `dd('Here');` before `if (!$project)`.

Comment: @Qirel yes.. it reaches the part inside `if(!$project)`.

Comment: can you hide the this code `'created_at' => $created_at,
                        'updated_at' => $updated_at` for test ? and check

Comment: it will never reach in inside of you if block . you should do this if(is_null($project)){ //your code }

Comment: first() method retun null if record not found else it returns an object. so you should check for null instead of false

Comment: try to create custom array under foreach loop then run create function in outside the foreach loop its working try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instances with Model::create(). It works the same way as make but it doesn't save it.

It is possible different ways: you can use the mass assignment without saving.

Please remember to set first the $fillable property in your model.

**WAY #1**: using the method fill

```
$model = new YourModel;

$model->fill([
    'field' => 'value',
    'another_field' => 'another_value'
]);

$model->save();
```

**WAY #2**: using the constructor

```
$model = new YourModel([
    'field' => 'value',
    'another_field' => 'another_value'
]);

$model->save();
```

**WAY #3**: like your current code`

```
$model = YourModel::create([
    'field' => 'value',
    'another_field' => 'another_value'
]);
```

Comment: I think we don't need `$model->save();` when use Model::create([]);
btw your help is ok

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as object instead:

```
$obj = new \App\Project;
$obj->client_code = $pjt['client_name'];
$obj->project_id = $pjt['id'];
...
$obj->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all change your if statement block because first() does not return boolean. it returns object or null. so you should check for null

```
 if(is_null($project))
  {
   // your create code 
  }
```